# How are new Chinese characters created?

Tags: characters, simplified-characters, orthography

What is the process for introducing a new Chinese character with custom meaning? What are the rules, what is not allowed, what is allowed? Who is allowed to create one? How do you associate a sound with it too? Is it free to create your own?

Comment: Do these threads not answer your questions: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/817/4136 && https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/22056/4136?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ancient time Chinese people were creating new characters. Now they don't. Only new chemical elements create new character.

> What are the rules, what is not allowed, what is allowed?

六書造字原則 is one of the rules.

> Who is allowed to create one? How do you associate a sound with it too? Is it free to create your own?

As far as I know, empirer and his government was allowed to create. 武則天 created 曌 for her own name. There were government officers who controlled the writing system. They might work on characters.

Comment: Would it be possible to [edit] in reliable references to support the first claim?